# tilemap collision detection not working properly on slower computers

Tags: c++, sfml, collision, game-development

notes:

- room1Collisions is a 1D array containing 1s and 0s representing collidable tiles.
- +/- 0.1 is used so that the player can still move when against a collidable tile.
- size is an SFML vector that holds the width and height of the player.
- I understand that this code is not in great shape, but I'm trying to get collisions working to then refactor.
- The issue (described below) occurs more frequently when the player collides diagonally

code:

```
void Player::Update(float dt) {
// 0 is a collidable tile
// change room1Collisions to a pointer of current level
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
{
    // a is top left and b is bottom left
    sf::Vector2u a(position.x/tileSize.x, (position.y+size.y/2)/tileSize.y);
    sf::Vector2u b(position.x/tileSize.x, (position.y+size.y-0.1)/tileSize.y);
    int tileNumberA = room1Collisions[(a.x) + a.y*(tilemapBounds.x/tileSize.x)];
    int tileNumberB = room1Collisions[(b.x) + b.y*(tilemapBounds.x/tileSize.x)];
    if (tileNumberA != 0 && tileNumberB != 0 && position.x >= 0) {
        position.x -= speed * dt;
        //animation.resumeAnimation();
    }
    direction = LEFT;
    //animation.resumeAnimation();
}
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
{
    sf::Vector2u a((position.x+size.x)/tileSize.x, (position.y+size.y/2)/tileSize.y);
    sf::Vector2u b((position.x+size.x)/tileSize.x, (position.y+size.y-0.1)/tileSize.y);
    int tileNumberA = room1Collisions[(a.x) + a.y*(tilemapBounds.x/tileSize.x)];
    int tileNumberB = room1Collisions[(b.x) + b.y*(tilemapBounds.x/tileSize.x)];
    if (tileNumberA != 0 && tileNumberB != 0 && position.x+size.x <= tilemapBounds.x) {
        position.x += speed * dt;
        //animation.resumeAnimation();
    }
    direction = RIGHT;
}
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
{
    sf::Vector2u a((position.x+0.1)/tileSize.x, (position.y+(size.y/3))/tileSize.y);
    sf::Vector2u b((position.x+size.x-0.1)/tileSize.x, (position.y+(size.y/3))/tileSize.y);
    int tileNumberA = room1Collisions[(a.x) + a.y*(tilemapBounds.x/tileSize.x)];
    int tileNumberB = room1Collisions[(b.x) + b.y*(tilemapBounds.x/tileSize.x)];
    if (tileNumberA != 0 && tileNumberB != 0 && position.y >= 0) {
        position.y -= speed * dt;
        //animation.resumeAnimation();
    }
    direction = UP;
    //animation.resumeAnimation();
}
if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
{
    sf::Vector2u a((position.x+0.1)/tileSize.x, (position.y+size.y)/tileSize.y);
    sf::Vector2u b((position.x+size.x-0.1)/tileSize.x, (position.y+size.y)/tileSize.y);
    int tileNumberA = room1Collisions[(a.x) + a.y*(tilemapBounds.x/tileSize.x)];
    int tileNumberB = room1Collisions[(b.x) + b.y*(tilemapBounds.x/tileSize.x)];
    if (tileNumberA != 0 && tileNumberB != 0 && position.y+size.y <= tilemapBounds.y) {
        position.y += speed * dt;
        //animation.resumeAnimation();
    }
    direction = DOWN;
}
//animation.setAnimation(direction);
//animation.Update(dt, 0.2f);
//animation.setPosition(position);
box.setPosition(position);
}
```

The problem is that when the game is run on slower computers, sometimes the player will skip (?) a collision check and it becomes stuck in a collidable tile, preventing it from moving orthogonally with respect to the collidable tile. On faster computers this issue is not present unless the player speed (currently 30) is increased significantly.

Below is an image showing the player inside a collidable tile. Please note that in this example the player is not able to move left/right since those directions are perpendicular to the collidable tile, but can still move up.

[image: problem]

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to regulate the FPS so that it is consistent for all computers.

Frame rate regulation example(This uses the SDL2 library for SDL_GetTicks and SDL_Delay but there are probably alternatives to that depending on your graphics library):

```
const int FPS = 60;
const int frameDelay = 1000/FPS;

Uint32 frameStart;
int frameTime;

//Main game loop
while (true)
{
    //Gets the amount of milliseconds elapsed since the program was first run
    frameStart = SDL_GetTicks();

    //YOUR MAIN GAME LOOP HERE

    //Gets the amount of milliseconds that it took to run the game loop
    frameTime = SDL_GetTicks() - frameStart;

    //Checks if the game loop was run faster than the max frame time
    if(frameDelay > frameTime)
    {
        //Delays the game loop so that it takes that the frame time always is the same
        SDL_Delay(frameDelay - frameTime);
    }
}
```

(Keep in mind that this is just an example there are lots of ways to regulate the FPS)

After implementing FPS regulation you might need to tweak the speed and collision sensitivity a little but once you have it it should be consistent on ALL computers

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. Isn't this the same as calculating delta time and multiplying player speed by it? Like in your example, I calculate delta time and use it in most of my update methods to ensure everything is the same on different computers. Or is your approach with an if statement something else? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes that basically does the same thing. It mostly comes down to personal preference.

Comment: Any idea why it might be giving me the issue with the double time already implemented?

Comment: It might be because you are changing the movement of the player to accommodate for slow processing, but you are not changing how it checks for collision. For example, say the player was 10 pixels away from the object and moving towards it at a speed of 3, and suddenly there is a 5 millisecond delay. The next time the loop runs after the delay, it will notice that it skipped 5 milliseconds so it will just multiply your speed of 3 by the 5 milliseconds moving you 15 pixels, which puts you 5 pixels inside of the object which prevents you from moving.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! How could I use my double time variable, dt, in my collision code to fix this?

Comment: I can't think of any easy way to do this. I would recommend try to delaying the frame rate instead(which would involve getting rid of the dt all together) because that will affect the entire program consistently